# Differences Between DataSet Merges

Tags: c#, object, initialization, dataset

Is there a difference (performance, overhead) between these two ways of merging data sets?

```
MyTypedDataSet aDataSet = new MyTypedDataSet();
aDataSet .Merge(anotherDataSet);
aDataSet .Merge(yetAnotherDataSet);
```

and

```
MyTypedDataSet aDataSet = anotherDataSet;
aDataSet .Merge(yetAnotherDataSet);
```

Which do you recommend?

Comment: the title is plain wrong - this is not a question about object initialization, this is a question about DataSet.Merge method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Keith is right, I suppose the example was simply badly chosen. Generally, it is better to initialize to the “right” object from the beginning and *not* construct an intermediate, empty object as in your case. Two reasons:

1. Performance. This should be obvious: Object creation costs time so creating less objects is better.
2. *Much* more important however, it better states your **intent**. You do generally *not* intend to create stateless/empty objects. Rather, you intend to create objects with some state or content. Do it. No need to create a useless (because empty) temporary.

Comment: Also, for some cases (but not the example) if you fully initialize the object at creation time, the object can be immutable.

Answer (score 5):

Those two lines do different things.

The first one creates a new set, and then merges a second set into it.

The second one sets the ds reference to point to the second set, so:

```
MyTypedDataSet ds1 = new MyTypedDataSet();
ds1.Merge(anotherDataSet);
//ds1 is a copy of anotherDataSet
ds1.Tables.Add("test")

//anotherDataSet does not contain the new table

MyTypedDataSet ds2 = anotherDataSet;
//ds12 actually points to anotherDataSet
ds2.Tables.Add("test");

//anotherDataSet now contains the new table
```

---

Ok, let's assume that what you meant was:

```
MyClass o1 = new MyClass();
o1.LoadFrom( /* some data */ );

//vs

MyClass o2 = new MyClass( /* some data */ );
```

Then the latter is better, as the former creates an empty object before populating it.

However unless initialising an empty class has a high cost or is repeated a large number of times the difference is not that important.

Answer (score 4):

Your second example does **not** create a new dataset.  It's just a second *reference* to an existing dataset.